# Changing the New Android Application defaults

Tags: android, default

In the New Android Application dialog box how do you permanently change the default setting for...

- Min Required SDK
- Target SDK
- Compile with
- Theme

I would like them all set to "API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo)".

Comment: Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to affect those would be to recompile from source. And note that "Theme" cannot be "API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo)". Also note that choosing "Compile with" or "Target SDK" to be "API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo)" in 2013 is a bad idea.

Comment: Why can't this be done by changing the `default.properties` file in the workspace? I think it's possible ?

Comment: I'm working with Android Development Tools in Eclispe

Comment: Would also like to see this answered for Studio as well